# PrimeNG + Webpack

Tags: webpack, minify, webpack-dev-server, primeng

I just want to share my experience with the issue where many warnings like the one below appear when using PrimeNG and Webpack.

```
WARNING in ../MyProjectName/~/primeng/components/orderlist/orderlist.js
Cannot find source file '../../src/app/components/orderlist/orderlist.ts': Error: C               an't resolve '../../src/app/components/orderlist/orderlist.ts' in '...MyProjectName\node_modules\primeng\components\orderlist'
 @ ../MyProjectName/~/primeng/primeng.js 50:9-52

...
```

This is a problem with the hardcoded route in all source mappings of primeng components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to exclude node_modules\primeng in your webpack.config.js:

```
    "enforce": "pre",
    "test": /\.js$/,
    "loader": "source-map-loader",
    "exclude": [
                /\/node_modules\//,
                path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng"),
     ]
```